# Windows 7 Less ram usage = less performance

Tags: windows-7, memory

I am using Windows 7. But I have a problem. My pc boots slowly for no reason. 1 day ago, it was fast and normal. But now it's lagging. Even the task manager is showing a static memory usage. It doesn't decrease or increase more fast. Also openning a file takes much longer (about 2 minutes to open a folder and 5 minutes to open google chrome).

The response time of my Windows is terrible!
How do I fix this.

Comment: Did you test memory?   Hardware test. Use memtest86.exe and make a bootable USB with Rufus to run the test.

Comment: Run deep antivirus checks, using at least your installed antivirus and also [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/). If no problem is found, check if this also happens when [booting in safe mode](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/what-safe-mode-how-boot-safe-mode/).

Comment: What changed before this issue? Install new apps? Also, if there's malware, rather than trying to remove it from an unsupported OS, try another, such as a newer Windows version, or Linux. If it;s a 32-bit machine, then Linux, such as Lubuntu 18.04 (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/) might be the *only* feasible option.

Comment: @ايمن - RDZ  - you should respond to (1) the possibility of a hardware issue (old machine) and (2) the possibility of malware.   Windows 7 is long dead and highly insecure.  Bad virus means reinstalling Windows 7 which is problematic because of the lack of updates.  Hardware issue means repair which most likely is uneconomical.   Time to think about a new computer with a supported operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also openning a file takes much longer

For me, it looks more like your filesystem is corrupted.

I recommend running `chkdsk C: /f /r` in CMD with admin privileges to scan and fix your hard drive.